# How can I import code and markdown cells from Python to Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

For version control reasons, I must save my code in `.py` files.

I would like to be able to able to import cells of Python code and Markdown documentation from `.py` files to Jupyter notebook.

For example, I would like to use Jupyter notebook to run my report code, which has multiple sections of code and documentation.

I am aware of the built-in `%run` and `%load` in Jupyter:

```
%run report.py
%load report.py
```

`%run` and `%load` run/load everything into one cell. I am looking for a solution which allows me to split a single python file to multiple notebook cells.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The accepted answers are different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have used 'p2j' to convert python file (.py) to ipython notebook file (.ipynb).

Try using the below steps:

1. pip install p2j
2. p2j your_python_file.py

For more details, refer https://github.com/raibosome/python2jupyter

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an iPython extension which does this: [ipython-cells](https://github.com/uiuc-sine/ipython-cells).

It can be used like this:

```
$ pip install ipython-cells
```

```py
>>> %load_ext ipython_cells
>>> %load_file test.py
>>> %cell_run 1
hello
>>> %cell_run 2
world
```

And the test file `test.py`

```py
# In[1]
print('hello')
# In[2]
print('world')
```

It also supports cell range execution and Spyder cell delimiters.  See the readme.

Comment: Can ipython-cells also be used to load the code of a code cell of one jupyter notebook into the code cell of another jupyter notebook?

Comment: It doesn't really "load" cells into anything.  It evals blocks of code delimited by comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try the built in

```
%load script.py
```

And do a little editing. Good If It has little markdown.

Learn the keyboard shortcut to split cell and convert to markdown.